# How to solve the following system of ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\boldsymbol{x}(t)=\left[x_1(t),\cdots,x_n(t)\right]^T$ ($n\geq 3$) then how to solve the following ODE?
$$\frac{d}{dt}\boldsymbol{x}=\boldsymbol{M}_{n\times n}\boldsymbol{x},\quad M_{n\times n}\in \rm{Skew}(n,\Bbb R).$$

Comment: Are you sure about the $X(0)$ on the right hand side? Shouldn't this be just $X$?

Comment: maybe! I think your are right.

Comment: I edited your question and introduced \\boldsymbol{...} to denote vectors. I also replaced your $X$ by a small $\boldsymbol{x}$ as normally we think of capital letters as matrices and not vectors.